# How do I show the menu bar window programmatically in Swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit

I'm trying to programmatically open MenuBarExtra in Swift on macOS using a global keyboard shortcut. I've already setup all the code for the keyboard shortcut but I can't figure out how to show/hide the MenuBarExtra using SwiftUI. Is there a way of doing so in native SwiftUI which I can't seem to find? Otherwise, is there a way of doing so via AppKit?

I've defined my menubar app the in the following way:

```
MenuBarExtra("Title", image: "sample_icon", content: {
      ContentView()
         .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

I'm using HotKey (https://github.com/soffes/HotKey )

My keyUpHandler looks like this:

```
{
let statusItem = NSApp.windows.first?.value(forKey: "statusItem") as? NSStatusItem
statusItem?.button?.performClick(nil)
}
```

Works for both .menu and .window menuBarExtraStyle